# Feasibility Study

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, meaning-in-context

What is an alternative for the phrase "feasibility study"? It does not need to be a phrase already in common use. The replacement(s) need to be more approachable and free of industry jargon (in this case the industry is architecture) but something that communicates the basic concept.

In the architecture industry the phrase "feasibility study" is tied to a specific list of questions that need to be answered about a project well before major commitments are made, e.g. purchasing land. Many people we work with don't know the phrase well or might even be intimidated by "feasibility study".

Comment: Is the thing you want a name for different from the feasibility study you describe?  Possibly the correct plan is to educate your clients on what is meant by this technical term?

Comment: You could call it a "preliminary assessment" or similar, but I doubt there's any other short well-known term besides "feasibility study" that *specifically* implies *make sure the project is at least **do-able in principle** before committing further resources*.

Comment: Would you mind explaining? Who are these customers? Small business owners, for example? I'm a firm believer in explanatory parentheses: feasibility study (whether the project is doable at reasonable cost)

Comment: @puppetsock The thing I want to name is not different from a feasibility study. I am just concerned about use of the phrase when talking to clients that I need to educate. And I hope to use the alternate phrase while introducing them to the concept of a feasibility study. But, maybe you are right. I should just use the phrase. It's not scary.

Comment: @Lambie The clients can be small business, or home owners, who are working on their first architecture project.

Comment: You can often make things sound less intimidating by changing nouns into verbs, so you could think about *we are looking into the feasibility of... * / *we would like to understand the feasibility of...* / *we would like your help understanding whether it would be feasible...* etc.

Answer (score -1):

You could try "preliminary study" or "first look at" or "preliminary review". It depends on context and just how informal you want it to sound.

Comment: "Fist look?" Is it a typo?

Comment: @puppetsock Well spotted.